# Ethernet: Intel 82567LM appears in lspci but no interface is populated

Tags: ethernet, kernel-module

[(x-post: sourceforge)](https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/662/)

[e1000e kernel module doc](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/e1000e.txt)

The Intel 82567LM **ethernet** adapter on my [ThinkPad X200](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X200) is not working. It appears in `lspci`, but **no interface** is populated according to `ip link`. How may I configure the device properly and get some ethernet?

[These](https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/1304/416327/1167987) [two](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/intel-r82567lm-3-gigabit-ethernet-card-is-not/384f398d-0b00-4536-a45b-3924b65b3899) might be of some help but ethtool is impossible since there is no interface at all

Distro: Archlinux.

uname -a

```
Linux HP-Arch 5.5.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed, 18 Mar 2020 08:40:35 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

ip link

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:f5:7a:96:a0:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
```

lspci | grep -i eth

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

lspci -s 00:19.0 -vv

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T400
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
    Region 0: Memory at f2600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Region 1: Memory at f2624000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Region 2: I/O ports at 1820 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI+ D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst- PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=1 PME-
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee02004  Data: 4029
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        AFCap: TP+ FLR+
        AFCtrl: FLR-
        AFStatus: TP-
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

lsmod | grep e1000e

```
e1000e                290816  0
```

modinfo e1000e

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.5.10-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e1000e/e1000e.ko.xz
version:        3.2.6-k
license:        GPL v2
description:    Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
author:         Intel Corporation, <linux.nics@intel.com>
srcversion:     AC8716ABC5C9AEE0D41D8DF
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015FAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015F9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015FCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015FBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D55sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D53sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D4Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D4Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D4Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00000D4Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015BCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015BEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015BDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015D6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015E3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015D8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015D7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015B9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015B8sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015B7sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001570sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000156Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000015A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001559sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000155Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000153Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000153Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001503sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001502sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010EAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001525sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CEsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010CBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BFsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010E5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000294Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BDsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C2sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001501sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001049sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010C5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000104Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BBsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001098sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001096sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000150Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010F6sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D3sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000109Asv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Csv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000108Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000107Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010B9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010DAsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010D9sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00001060sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A5sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010BCsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d000010A4sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Fsv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000105Esv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           e1000e
vermagic:       5.5.10-arch1-1 SMP preempt mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        57:76:27:85:D2:BD:74:81:95:24:2D:45:91:E0:24:6E:89:E1:4D:21
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      81:EC:C6:B1:B4:9F:46:C0:45:03:BA:AD:74:A1:F2:4A:2B:52:EE:01:
        38:AA:59:74:11:56:64:1A:C1:68:5C:92:8E:A2:F0:69:CB:A9:08:B1:
        31:22:0C:0E:F3:98:01:85:F5:FF:06:0F:68:C4:AC:3B:01:96:ED:1F:
        0F:86:9C:F5:AC:F7:00:A8:1C:21:B4:90:BE:FC:A5:F8:8E:95:00:F7:
        16:A4:89:29:8B:0F:34:48:1D:AC:7A:6D:90:43:4A:58:C0:3A:37:17:
        FE:E5:2F:CF:FA:68:98:1E:77:7B:E7:FF:AD:9B:42:48:79:F1:3F:28:
        ED:7E:97:56:7F:35:87:95:29:57:0E:B6:BB:08:64:B0:0A:B0:21:B2:
        52:46:73:5A:59:C4:17:4F:E3:A4:FA:DF:A3:03:16:51:E7:20:A3:C1:
        42:8B:EA:83:F5:EE:87:7C:C5:91:75:DC:B8:C2:CE:A6:5A:36:3A:71:
        24:DB:3A:16:E3:04:D1:E3:04:7C:5F:4B:BA:FC:10:F5:04:33:86:AE:
        39:55:AB:BC:CB:AF:7F:89:C5:E9:B3:46:AB:71:04:47:2F:1E:52:79:
        E5:0A:7F:B4:B3:62:E1:E5:FA:90:9D:FF:3B:D2:6B:BB:38:A5:A2:06:
        A6:15:2F:2C:99:17:A2:69:61:1B:05:31:90:5E:5C:90:2F:49:C8:78:
        54:5B:67:B5:0C:97:3E:75:4F:81:2B:3E:F1:31:B1:FE:A5:C6:06:D9:
        A4:C7:AD:A9:75:E6:DD:83:39:FF:3D:5E:89:E3:C9:81:FA:D0:CF:0C:
        A9:D6:C3:71:32:04:2F:EA:38:47:30:7F:25:C6:18:14:B9:B2:F9:A7:
        22:72:E6:7C:BC:08:81:C7:AE:0D:D5:C9:2D:38:1A:EB:53:75:77:9D:
        C0:3E:D3:2B:3D:0A:35:35:FC:13:A0:EB:5A:44:F8:3D:D6:05:59:69:
        BB:13:F9:7C:D1:65:D9:C4:50:1D:B5:65:8F:B9:2F:12:13:D7:CC:4A:
        98:7B:BA:7F:68:7B:A7:DE:B1:DD:5F:5F:F5:69:3C:BF:79:8D:AB:75:
        B3:79:7A:69:14:37:9A:51:9D:64:87:94:1E:7C:0C:9F:3D:C5:26:1A:
        CA:3D:2A:93:BB:D3:0E:E4:EF:9E:B1:76:B0:22:14:BD:83:E4:DF:9A:
        0B:B9:89:F6:A0:49:C8:EF:6C:F0:83:07:57:2F:EA:95:21:F1:42:BE:
        22:E1:28:55:7D:D5:1F:82:4D:07:10:5B:5A:84:79:ED:46:BD:4C:4E:
        E1:97:DE:4B:02:5B:83:38:42:B5:AF:87:74:2C:D1:92:9D:0C:20:CD:
        5C:E2:CF:0A:9E:50:21:18:9C:BA:CF:5C
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int)
parm:           copybreak:Maximum size of packet that is copied to a new buffer on receive (uint)
parm:           TxIntDelay:Transmit Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           TxAbsIntDelay:Transmit Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxIntDelay:Receive Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           RxAbsIntDelay:Receive Absolute Interrupt Delay (array of int)
parm:           InterruptThrottleRate:Interrupt Throttling Rate (array of int)
parm:           IntMode:Interrupt Mode (array of int)
parm:           SmartPowerDownEnable:Enable PHY smart power down (array of int)
parm:           KumeranLockLoss:Enable Kumeran lock loss workaround (array of int)
parm:           WriteProtectNVM:Write-protect NVM [WARNING: disabling this can lead to corrupted NVM] (array of int)
parm:           CrcStripping:Enable CRC Stripping, disable if your BMC needs the CRC (array of int)
```

Comment: That is an older laptop. Try this article below to see if it helps. You need to compile your own kernel.  Also see if you can find a USB Ethernet Card that might work better.  http://comcap.free.fr/Index/x200s.html

Comment: @John  Sorry but site is down https://www.isitdownrightnow.com/comcap.free.fr.html

Comment: It was live when I posted, so wait until it comes back

Comment: Remember this is an old laptop.  Try this site below and also a USB Ethernet Adapter.  https://justinsomnia.org/2008/09/getting-wireless-to-work-in-ubuntu-on-a-lenovo-thinkpad-x200/

Comment: It's not wireless...

Comment: USB Adapters come in both Ethernet and Wireless.  Try an Ethernet adapter

Comment: Thanks. Nice idea. But it used to work a month ago. Is it possible to mitigate this w/o downgrading kernel & modules?

Comment: I do not know the answer to the last question. It has been a long time since I used that class of ThinkPad. Ethernet drivers were problematic back then.

Comment: First step is to look in `dmesg` directly after boot, and see if there are any errors.